# Group item from an array when their value are equal

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and would like to group some item if some specs are equal.

Here my initial array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2012-12-12
        [NDC_Type] => Item
        [NDC_Item] => Extra Bed
        [NDC_Rate] => 0.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Status] => Charged
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2013-02-02
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Item] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 1000.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 10
        [NDC_Status] => Charged
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [NDC_Date] => 2013-02-03
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Item] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 1000.00
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Quantity] => 2
        [NDC_Status] => Charged
    )
)
```

So the goal is to group the item into this array when:

- `NDC_Rate` is equal
- `NDC_Type` is equal
- `NDC_Taxes` is equal
- `NDC_TaxesName` is equal
- `NDC_Quantity` is equal
- `NDC_Status` is equal

So I should compare each item to know that.

Actually my code is this one.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $k = $item['NDC_Item'];

    if (!isset($result[$k])) {
        $result[$k] = $item;
    } elseif (
        ($i = $result[$k]) && 
        $item['NDC_Rate'] === $i['NDC_Rate'] && 
        $item['NDC_Type'] === $i['NDC_Type'] && 
        $item['NDC_Taxes'] === $i['NDC_Taxes'] && 
        $item['NDC_TaxesName'] === $i['NDC_TaxesName'] && 
        $item['NDC_Quantity'] === $i['NDC_Quantity'] &&
        $item['NDC_Status']=== $i['NDC_Status'] 
    ) {
        $current_dates = explode(', ', $result[$k]['NDC_Date']);
        $last_date = end($current_dates);
        if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$last_date} +1 day")) === $item['NDC_Date']) {
            $result[$k]['NDC_Id'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Id'];
            $result[$k]['NDC_Date'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Date'];
        } else {
            $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
        }
    } else {
        $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

It do not make anything as the final array returned is the same as the one I gave.

Is there a reason? What I'm doing wrong with this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To shorten your code: `function equals($a,$b,$fields){ foreach($fields as $f){ if($a[$f]!=$b[$f]) return false;} return true; }` call it like `equals($a,$b,array('NDC_Rate','NDC_Type'));`

Comment: By the way this `$k. microtime()` makes it hard to follow your code flow. Why `microtime`?

Comment: @F__M There is no `$item['NDC_Id']` in your sample array, please update your question, so that a solution can be provided without making assumptions in the data.  Furthermore, for highest clarity, please provide your expected result array so we can see the exact structure you wish to achieve without trying to interpret your non-functioning attempt.